# Timeout error when accessing git repo in Jenkins Integration

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, github, jenkins

All,

We are having continous Jenkins Integration, It was working fine before couple of days and now we are getting a different error and cannot build the app

Started by user Kiran 
Building in workspace /Users/administrator/.jenkins/jobs/iOS_Dev_CC/workspace

> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/m-ize/CC.git # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/m-ize/CC.git
>   git --version # timeout=10
>   git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/m-ize/CC.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
>   git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
>   Checking out Revision d936d252dc4f71a9a9cb4533b66c13d4a4cd94b0 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
>   git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>   git checkout -f d936d252dc4f71a9a9cb4533b66c13d4a4cd94b0
>   git rev-list d936d252dc4f71a9a9cb4533b66c13d4a4cd94b0 # timeout=10
>   [workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/km/33wcncls1874x2xv50nv43480000gn/T/hudson2643925333548497591.sh
>   + rm -fr CC.xcworkspace
>   + rm -fr /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
>   + rm -fr Pods/
>   + rm -rf '/Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*'
>   + pod install
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:318:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0.a) among 30 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
>   Checked in 'GEM_PATH=file:/Users/administrator/.jenkins/plugins/ruby-runtime/WEB-INF/lib/stapler-jruby-1.209.jar!/gem:/Users/administrator/Software/ruby', execute`gem env`for more information
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:327:in`to_spec'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
>       from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in`'
>   Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

It is a private repo,

We are able clone it in our local machines regularly

Comment: can you run "pod --version" from terminal and share the results?

Comment: This is the version 1.0.0 of pod

Comment: share your podfile.lock contents

Comment: Actually I have deleted the complete workspace before starting the Build, I feel pod.lock file may not effect, We are getting this issues for all projects we have

Comment: try to update your pod master repo then reinstall pods on directly

Comment: Ok Thanks will try